# Javascript Sensors API not working on iOS

Tags: javascript

I've been programming a web application which needs to access the accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope. I was using the Accelerometer, Magnetometer and Gyroscope API.  But when I tested on iOS it didn't work. Then I realized that now it is needed to request permission in iOS to use them. But this permission request only works on DeviceOrentation and DeviceMotion APIs. Is there a way to request permission on these APIs?

Comment: I dont have an iPhone but Im told that alot of the functionality on an iPhone wont work without an express gesture from the user being the triggering event. For example, if you want to play music on an android browser you go playMusic() anywhere but on an iPhone, playMusic() will only work when called through something like an eventListener. Ive never had an iPhone to check this "feature" out for myself but it seems like the kind of headache your experiencing here. I found this information out writing for the webaudio API and it kind of put me off not having iOS to test it out on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Feature support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_sensor) is patchy and unknown, but the new [Generic Sensors API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs) may be what you're looking for. It allows you to use all of the above sensors with permission from the user.